# Keeping answer as Draft (Submit later)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, draft

Is there any option to keep the answer as draft and submit later. I need it for the following reasons.

1. I'm writing a big answer, suddenly my browser is crashed and I lost all.
2. I need to add more code in the answer that take sometime.

I've searched in meta but couldn't get answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your answer. Keep writing it.

After a while, if the browser you use supports local storage (and the answer is long enough), it will get saved as a draft. This is indicated by a link - discard next to the "Post Your Answer" button.

> [image: discard]

Don't post the answer - close your browser and go back to it. It will still be there.

You can remove the draft by clicking the discard link.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Can I somewhere get back the question (with draft answer) again ?

Comment: @vels4j - You just go back to the question. The draft answer will be there (assuming you are on the same machine and browser). There is no UI to find all questions that have a saved draft.

Comment: I write an answer, on my iPad. And I see the little message "draft saved". Then, on my computer, I write an answer to a different question, on the same site. Now, on my iPad, I go back to the draft. Will I find my draft ? Please reassure me. ;-)

Comment: Oded, thank you for your so quick answer ! But @JeffAtwood says somewhere that one answer draft is saved per user per site. Not per question. Per question would be much nicer. :-)

Comment: @Nicolas - I just checked the codebase, and the answer is that the darft is indeed per site (per user). It isn't per question, as I previously stated.